# How to access and compare two arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

By these lines, I got the two arrays:

```
@correct_answer = Question.pluck(:correct_answer)
# => [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]
@selected_answer = Question.pluck(:selected_answer)
# => [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]
```

How can I compare the values in these two arrays one by one? I use this code:

```
if @correct_answer[0] == @selected_answer[0]
  @result += 1
else
  @result -= 1
end
```

but that's not working.

Comment: This is meaningless unless you have provided an order for the values to be retrieved in, isn't it?

Comment: What result do you want from this?

Comment: i want when values are equal add +1 in result else -1 in result

Comment: yes its in proper order

Comment: "I want to iterate through one of the arrays, checking to see whether the value in the same position in the other array is equal to it or not, ..."

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: You can count correct answer this way:

```
correct_score = correct_answer.zip(selected_answer).count { |correct, wrong| correct == wrong }
# => 3
wrong_score = selected_answer.size - correct_score
# => 6
total_score = correct_score - wrong_score
# => -3
```

You can also find out what values match by this code:

```
correct_answer = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]
# => [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]
selected_answer = [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]
# => [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]
correct_answer.zip(selected_answer).map do |correct, selected| 
  correct == selected ? 'Correct!' : "Wrong! Correct answer is: #{correct}" 
end
# => ["Correct!", "Wrong! Correct answer is: 1", "Wrong! Correct answer is: 2", "Wrong! Correct answer is: 2", "Correct!", "Wrong! Correct answer is: 1", "Wrong! Correct answer is: 3", "Correct!", "Wrong! Correct answer is: 3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution

```
a1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]
a2 = [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]

a1.zip(a2).inject(0) do |result, (correct, selected)|
  result += (correct == selected ? 1 : -1)
end
# => -3
```

The explanation:

- with `zip` you merge `a1` and `a1` in a single array.
- you use `inject` to map and reduce the array starting from a base value of 0
- if the values match, you add +1, otherwise -1

Comment: but thats give me only 0 output

Comment: Maybe it's easier to separate the map and reduce steps, i.e. `a1.zip(a2).map { |x, y| x == y ? 1 : -1 }.inject(:+)`

Comment: i want to comapre each elements one by one with each other

Comment: @jasssingh that code effectively compares each result one by one. It does not give you 0 as output. Try the code I posted as it is. Also try to learn from it, don't just blindly copy the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
@selected_answers = [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]
@correct_answers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]

## This will return count of all matched and unmatched values.
@selected_answers.each_with_index do |selected_answer, index|
  if selected_answer == @correct_answers[index]
    @result += 1
  else
    @result -= 1
  end
end

## This will return count of only matched values.
@selected_answers.each_with_index do |selected_answer, index|
  @result += 1 if selected_answer == @correct_answers[index]
end
```

Comment: undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please paste your `@selected_answers` value

Comment: @selected_answers = [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]

Comment: Please paste your code if you are executing on rails console

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: [1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1]   [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3]  like 1=1 then add result =+1     else  result -=1      next this repeat till the last element 1 and 3

Comment: comparing all elements one by one with each other of both arrays

Comment: if you do this then it will return count of correct answers.

`@selected_answers.each_with_index do |selected_answer, index|
  @result += 1 if selected_answer == @correct_answers[index]
end`

Comment: thanks amit its working now , but there is little bit problam when value are not equal deduct 2 ponits from the result for one output

Answer (score 0):

```
@result = 0
@correct_answer = Question.pluck(:correct_answer)
@selected_answer = Question.pluck(:selected_answer)
@selected_answer.each_with_index do |selected_answer, index|
  @result += 1 if selected_answer == @correct_answer[index]
end
```

This code is working for me thanks to Amit sharma.

Comment: Instead duplicate an answer you should upvote useful ones and mark the answer that better fits to your problem as accepted.